# standard input is not a terminal device

Tags: bash, shell, serial-port, linux-device-driver

I am trying to execute a customised command to upgrade software.

```
executable-name -d /dev/ttySP1 -f media1/sda1/file.txt
```

this line is added in a shell script. gives below error when executed from shell script. runs independently from command prompt

'standard input is not a terminal device'

please comment if some one has faced same issue or has any idea.

I am using beaglebone . Linux os.

Comment: Seems like a little bit of a hack but you could try executing it via `unbuffer`.

Comment: Do you have that in a pipe?

Comment: `unbuffer` is a command provided by `expect` that will cause the program to see stdin/stdout as tty devices. For a more complete solution you jmight need to just use `expect`, but it's hard to say without any context.